# Unable to to see multiple CAs certificates in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, ssl, https, hp-ux

A newbie to Apache.  I have tried to implement multiple SSL CA Certs on my HP-UX, Apache 2.2 web server but, whenever I try to hit my site with a secondary CA cert, the site doesn't recognize it.

For example, I have DoD root certificates and ORC root certificates that I need to be able to access my site.  I have tried to use the SSLCACertificateFile directive by concatenating the certificates (with DoD certs first and then with ORC root certs first) and the site only recognizes the DoD certs - both times.  I have tried to use the SSLCACertificatePath directive, making the hash file links with the extensions being sequential, and only the DoD certs are seen.  The kicker is that I have tried to use the ORC certs ONLY with the SSLCACertificateFile directive and the DoD certs are the only ones that are seen.

I am stopping and starting my Apache process with each change.  My permissions for these tests are 777.  I am not seeing anything in the logs (another question as I expect my logs to be as verbose as IIS but my logs are at 0 bytes with a current time stamp).

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't an issue with the certificates per se, but, the server wasn't releasing the root process for httpd even though the 'stop' command returned successfully.

Therefore, had to do a 'sudo pkill -9 httpd' to release the root process after a 'stop.' When started again, all certificates were seen.